# What does "pollsys" mean? Solaris "truss" output

Tags: solaris, trace

```
> truss -p 6482
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000) (sleeping...)
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000) (sleeping...)
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000) (sleeping...)
/2:     pollsys(0xE517AD88, 1, 0xE517AE30, 0x00000000)  = 0
[...]
```

no manual page found. Please explain for Non-programmer.

```
> uname -a
SunOS toolbox048 5.10 Generic_139555-08 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320
```

Answer (score 4):

`pollsys` is a private system call on which are built the documented `poll`, `select` and `pselect` `libc` functions.

Answer (score 1):

It means "poll system". It's checking a memory location in expectation of some data that might be there. When it doesn't find it, it sleeps and tries again later.

I can't tell any more than that from what you included.